# How to withold specific properties in Django Rest Framework Serializer based on the logged in user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, authorization

I've got a Django Rest Framework API in which I only let logged in users POST new items. The ViewSet looks as follows:

```
class APIAuthGroup(InAuthGroup):
    """
    A permission to only allow WRITE/POST access if and only if a user is logged in,
    and is a member of the SA role inside keycloak.
    """
    allowed_group_names = [settings.KEYCLOAK_SA_WRITE_PERMISSION]

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS \
               or super(APIAuthGroup, self).has_permission(request, view)


class DevicesViewSet(DatapuntViewSetWritable):
    """
    A view that will return the devices and makes it possible to post new ones
    if the user is logged in
    """

    queryset = Device.objects.all().order_by('id')

    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
    serializer_detail_class = DeviceSerializer

    http_method_names = ['post', 'list', 'get']

    permission_classes = [APIAuthGroup]
```

And my serializer:

```
class PersonSerializer(HALSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False, max_length=255)
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    organisation = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'organisation')


class DeviceSerializer(HALSerializer):
    long = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    lat = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    organisation = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    owner = PersonSerializer()
    contact = PersonSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = (
            '_links',
            'id',
            'frequency',
            'longitude',
            'latitude',
            'organisation',
            'owner',
            'contact'
        )

    def get_organisation(self, obj):
        if obj.owner:
            return obj.owner.organisation
        return 'Onbekend'
```

I now only want the `owner` and the `contact` to be returned if the user is logged in and if the logged in user email address is equal to the `owner.email`.

I'm unsure how and where I would be able to do this though. Should I do this in the serializer, or in the viewset? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override serializer's [`to_representation`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-instance) method:

```
class DeviceSerializer(HALSerializer):
    long = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    lat = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    organisation = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    owner = PersonSerializer()
    contact = PersonSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = (
            '_links',
            'id',
            'frequency',
            'longitude',
            'latitude',
            'organisation',
            'owner',
            'contact'
        )

    def get_organisation(self, obj):
        if obj.owner:
            return obj.owner.organisation
        return 'Onbekend'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        if obj.owner != self.context["request"].user:
            data.pop("owner")  # remove from response
            data.pop("contact")  # remove from response
        return data
```

Note `self.context` attribute which contains request object. You can find more details about it [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).